# MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID invalid column

Tags: android, database, mediastore

I can't get the albumID from MediaStore, i get -1 from `getColumnIndex`. Here is my code:

```
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst() == false)
    {
            //no rows empty cursor
    }
    int albumColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Albums.ALBUM);
    int albumidColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID);
    String album = cursor.getString(albumColumnIndex);
    int id = cursor.getInt(albumidColumnIndex);

    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        album = cursor.getString(albumColumnIndex);
        id = cursor.getInt(albumidColumnIndex);
    }
```

For some reason `getColumnIndex(Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID);` returns -1, does anyone know why could that be? Album name works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently `_ID` is `ALBUM_ID` for `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID`. Docs for MediaStore are really bad.

Comment: I just found this out myself. Thanks for assuring me on this. However MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID is valid in context of audio, instead of album. I vote up just for this.