# MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI reported as Unknown URI

Tags: android, file, android-contentprovider

```
Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, audioValues);
```

on some devices **yields**:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external/audio/media
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2887)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external/audio/media
>          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
>          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>          at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
>          at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1231)
>          at company.app.MainService.setupFilesForAudioRecording(MainService.java:388)
>          at company.app.MainService.onCreate(MainService.java:239)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2877)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I don't understand how it is possible I would ever get this **error**.  How can MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI be an unknown URI?  Is this a situation where the device does not have external storage?

[Developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) say:

> External storage is not always available, because the user can mount the external storage as USB storage and in some cases remove it from the device.

But that seems like a very rare case.

Comment: Because your uri is not correct?

Comment: Reading the error usually get's you somewhere. It says right there that that URI isn't correct.

Comment: whats the valus of `audioValues`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert audio album in Android MediaStore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018173/insert-audio-album-in-android-mediastore)

Comment: The URI is correct assuming URI is referring to MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI...the error message is just bad.  I think the issue was the file path of the DATA(path) audioValue is non-existing for some users as @PavneetSingh alluded to.  Needed to create the directory if not already created.  Will see if that solves...if not will open this back up

Comment: @AndrewLi how can the URI be incorrect when it is a constant coming from Android framework?  And lose the sarcasm, you clearly didn't understand the question.

Comment: @SohailZahid should it matter?  The error is saying MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is an unknown URI when it is a constant from [Android framework](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

Answer (score 1):

This exception is related with the `path` of either `resource` or `directory`.Follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018173/insert-audio-album-in-android-mediastore) to see the code example.

Edit : It could be possible that some device does not have external storage so you should add couple of checks before executing any storage operation.

```
// call this function , if true , go ahead ,storage available
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That link is a different error message...not related.

Comment: @ericwjr you can use [Checking media availability](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) to confirm the existence of external storage and not all devices