# album_info does not contain album_id column error

Tags: android

I'm creating a music player that populates an array list with song objects. Each song object has a series of attributes. One of those attributes is the album-art URI.

This is the line of code where I assign the URI attribute to the song object.

```
songObject.albumArtURI = GetAlbumArtURI(albumID);
```

Here is the string value of `albumID`

```
Log.v("TAG",String.valueOf(albumID)); // prints [Ljava.lang.String;@44ce53d
```

When I pass `albumID` to `GetAlbumArtURI()` method

```
private String GetAlbumArtURI(String[] albumID){

    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART}, 
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID + "=?", 
            albumID, // Error 
            null
    );

    return mCursor.getString(0);

}
```

I get this error:

```
no such column: album_id (code 1)
while compiling: 
SELECT album_art FROM album_info WHERE (album_id=?)
```

The error essentially says that table [album_info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.html) does not contain `album_id` column. But according to the documenation, [album_info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.html) does have such a column.

Comment: @jyanks I am not creating tables. I am accessing meta data tables. They should already be there.

Comment: Sorry, disregard my previous comment. Can you try `MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?"`

Comment: That gives me this error `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1` which I think is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996228/mediastore-audio-albums-album-id-invalid-column) so I think my syntax is correct... I posted the string value of `albumID` Does it look correct to you?

Comment: Is there any effect if you add the album_id field to the projection array?

Comment: @jyanks nope. I get the same error.

Comment: Where is that album id coming from? I have the code running here as well and it looks like that -1 requested error is a result of there being no results returned in the cursor (if you do `if(cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount() > 0)` it'll return false)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92334/discussion-between-jyanks-and-the-prole).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there's a few issues causing your query to return nothing and throw that error.

1. `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID` is not the column you want to reference. You should be using `MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID`.
2. You need to move your cursor's read position to the first position when you get results, if possible. Doing otherwise will result in you never getting the results you need
3. The way that `MediaStore` works on android is that you have to register the media files that you want the OS to know about - this isn't automatic. You need to implement something similar to the [SingleMediaScanner described in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile)

Here is the working bit of code that I have written:

```
try {
        final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",
                null,
                null
        );

        // You need to check if there are results in your cursor. 
        // This is like saying if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)
        if(mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),e.getMessage());
    }
```

When you have called that code, you're assuming that the MediaStore on your device knows about the music files you've downloaded or added. You can definitely implement a `BroadcastReceiver` to capture system events like files being added, but for this answer I'm just going to show how you account for one known file. You could also expand this to search an entire directory by adding to the `onMediaScannerConnected(...)` method.

If you implement the SingleMediaScanner file found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile) you can then just do:

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/1.mp3");
    SingleMediaScanner singleMediaScanner = new SingleMediaScanner(this, file);
```

And it will register the media file in your MediaStore. At that point, you should be able to get results back from your query above. If you are having doubts of whether or not the songs are being registered, you can check to see if any records have been added at all by changing your mCursor call to this (to get all the results in the media store) and then iterating through them:

```
 final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
```

Comment: How can I test if an individual media file has been registered with Media-store so I don't have to call  `SingleMediaScanner()` on each and every file every-time the music app is re-opened?

Comment: Really, you can check the media store for that file via the contentResolver query that you have above. I realize that's not ideal, so you could put all that discovery code into a background service or something like that and notify the UI layer when there are new files detected.

Comment: Do you think you could help me with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751762/unable-to-return-all-album-uris-with-content-resolver/33754002#33754002) which is related to the same topic. Thanks.