# Unable to return all album URIs with content resolver

Tags: android

I'm making a music player, and I noticed some of the other music players on the Play Store where able to display the entire set of album covers on my phone, where some of the other players, including my own, were not able to display them all.

I was able to set up a media scanner to register the music files in a given external file directory

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music");
new SingleMediaScanner(this, file);
```

Here is the scanner class, which uses recursion to search the entire `/Music` directory and registers files individually

```
public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
private File mFile;

public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
    mFile = f;
    mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
    mMs.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {

    listDirectory(mFile,1);
}

@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    mMs.disconnect();
}

public void listDirectory(File dirPath, int level) {

    // See code below

}
}
```

Here is `listDirectory()` method with recursion

```
public void listDirectory(File dirPath, int level) {

        //File dir = new File(dirPath);

        File[] firstLevelFiles = dirPath.listFiles();
        if (firstLevelFiles != null && firstLevelFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File aFile : firstLevelFiles) {
                if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
                    listDirectory(aFile, level + 1);
                } else {
                    Log.v("TAG file name",aFile.getName()); // Appears to be working
                    mMs.scanFile(aFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

But oddly enough, I could do without the entire scanner class, and the results would be the same. When I run a query for the album URIs, I still get `null` in return for the missing album cover URIs.

```
private String GetAlbumArtURI(String[] albumID) {

        final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",
                albumID,
                null
        );

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {

            return mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
        }
        else {
            mCursor.close();
            return null;
        }
}
```

I'm getting `albumID` from running another query on the music meta data.

**edit**

This how I call `GetAlbumArtURI`

```
songObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
scanMedia();
Cursor songListCursor = GetSongListCursor();
MakeLists(songListCursor);
```

`GetSongListCursor`

```
private Cursor GetSongListCursor() {

    Uri contentURI = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};

    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    String order = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, projection, selection, null, order);

    return mCursor;
}
```

`MakeLists()` is where I call `GetAlbumArtURI`

```
private void MakeLists(Cursor mCursor) {

        try{

            if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {

                do {

                    // Initialize songObject
                    SongObject songObject = new SongObject();

                    // Add albumURI
                    String[] albumID = {mCursor.getString(5)};
                    songObject.albumArtURI = GetAlbumArtURI(albumID);

                    // add albumTitle
                    String albumTitle = mCursor.getString(0);
                    songObject.albumTitle = albumTitle;

                    // Add artist or add "Unknown Artist"
                    String artist = mCursor.getString(1);
                    if (artist.equals("<unknown>")) {

                        artist = "Unknown Artist";
                        songObject.artist = artist;
                    }
                    else {

                        artist = mCursor.getString(1);
                        songObject.artist = artist;
                    }

                    String songTitle = mCursor.getString(2);
                    songObject.songTitle = songTitle;

                    String songPath = mCursor.getString(3);
                    songObject.songPath = songPath;

                    String songDuration = mCursor.getString(4);
                    songObject.songDuration = songDuration;

                    songObjectList.add(songObject);

                    String albumArtist = songObject.artist; 
                    String albumArtURI = songObject.albumArtURI;


                } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
            }

        } finally {

            mCursor.close();
        }
}
```

**edit**

The album IDS

```
11-17 00:50:17.287  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:17.297  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:17.307  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 25
11-17 00:50:17.327  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 25
11-17 00:50:17.337  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 25
11-17 00:50:17.347  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 25
11-17 00:50:17.347  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.357  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 22
11-17 00:50:17.367  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 22
11-17 00:50:17.367  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:17.367  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:17.377  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 14
11-17 00:50:17.387  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:17.417  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:17.427  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.427  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.437  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 6
11-17 00:50:17.437  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 22
11-17 00:50:17.447  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 6
11-17 00:50:17.457  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.467  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:17.467  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:17.477  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.477  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 19
11-17 00:50:17.477  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.487  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.487  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.497  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.497  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 23
11-17 00:50:17.507  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.527  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.557  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.577  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.587  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.587  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 6
11-17 00:50:17.597  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.597  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.607  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:17.607  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.607  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.617  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.617  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 17
11-17 00:50:17.627  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 17
11-17 00:50:17.627  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:17.637  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.647  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 13
11-17 00:50:17.647  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:17.657  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:17.657  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.667  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:17.667  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 9
11-17 00:50:17.677  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.677  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:17.677  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.687  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.687  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:17.697  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 26
11-17 00:50:17.697  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 6
11-17 00:50:17.697  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:17.707  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:17.707  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.717  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 20
11-17 00:50:17.717  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 17
11-17 00:50:17.717  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 6
11-17 00:50:17.727  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:17.727  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:17.737  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 13
11-17 00:50:17.737  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:17.737  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:17.747  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 22
11-17 00:50:17.747  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:17.757  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 21
11-17 00:50:17.757  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.767  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:17.767  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:17.767  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:17.777  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 13
11-17 00:50:17.777  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.787  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:17.787  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:17.787  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.797  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 19
11-17 00:50:17.797  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:17.807  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:17.807  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.817  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.817  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.827  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 22
11-17 00:50:17.827  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.827  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.837  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:17.837  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 17
11-17 00:50:17.847  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:17.847  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:17.847  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.857  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.857  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:17.867  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:17.867  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 19
11-17 00:50:17.877  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.877  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 26
11-17 00:50:17.887  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.887  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 19
11-17 00:50:17.897  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 13
11-17 00:50:17.897  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 9
11-17 00:50:17.907  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 26
11-17 00:50:17.907  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 14
11-17 00:50:17.917  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:17.917  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 14
11-17 00:50:17.927  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 6
11-17 00:50:17.927  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.937  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 20
11-17 00:50:17.947  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 9
11-17 00:50:17.957  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 19
11-17 00:50:17.957  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.967  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.967  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.967  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:17.977  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 26
11-17 00:50:17.977  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:17.987  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 23
11-17 00:50:17.997  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:17.997  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:18.007  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:18.017  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:18.027  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:18.027  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:18.047  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:18.057  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:18.057  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:18.087  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:18.097  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.097  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 22
11-17 00:50:18.107  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.117  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.117  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 14
11-17 00:50:18.127  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.127  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 2
11-17 00:50:18.127  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.137  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.137  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.147  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 21
11-17 00:50:18.147  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:18.157  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:18.157  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 14
11-17 00:50:18.167  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 14
11-17 00:50:18.317  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.317  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 20
11-17 00:50:18.327  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:18.327  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 20
11-17 00:50:18.337  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.337  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 18
11-17 00:50:18.347  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 11
11-17 00:50:18.347  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:18.347  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 21
11-17 00:50:18.357  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.357  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 26
11-17 00:50:18.367  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 26
11-17 00:50:18.367  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.367  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 17
11-17 00:50:18.377  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.377  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 23
11-17 00:50:18.377  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 6
11-17 00:50:18.387  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 23
11-17 00:50:18.387  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.397  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 9
11-17 00:50:18.397  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:18.397  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 20
11-17 00:50:18.407  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 22
11-17 00:50:18.407  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 14
11-17 00:50:18.417  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.417  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.427  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 10
11-17 00:50:18.427  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 9
11-17 00:50:18.437  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.437  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.437  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.447  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 13
11-17 00:50:18.447  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 19
11-17 00:50:18.457  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.477  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.487  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.487  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 6
11-17 00:50:18.497  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 26
11-17 00:50:18.497  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.507  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 26
11-17 00:50:18.517  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 20
11-17 00:50:18.517  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:18.527  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 12
11-17 00:50:18.527  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.527  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 16
11-17 00:50:18.557  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 15
11-17 00:50:18.567  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.567  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 17
11-17 00:50:18.577  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.577  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 17
11-17 00:50:18.587  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 13
11-17 00:50:18.587  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 20
11-17 00:50:18.597  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 24
11-17 00:50:18.607  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 8
11-17 00:50:18.607  V/TAG ALBUM_ID: 23
```

Comment: where are you calling `GetAlbumArtURI` ? and how?

Comment: I added an edit addressing your question

Comment: did you try to call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` inside `GetSongListCursor` ? what are the values of `album_id` ?

Comment: The code for GetAlbumArt looks ok but you should store the result string in a variable, close the cursor and then return the result variable. Please show how you get the album ID.

Comment: @EmanuelSeidinger Thanks. What method should I close the cursor in? I get the album ID in `GetSongListCursor` where I make a query returning the ID.

Comment: @pskink No I did not. I added the album IDs in another edit.

Comment: In `GetAlbumArtUri` when `mCursor.moveToFirst()` returns true you read the String directly from the cursor and return it. But that's probably not solving your problem. Cursors just should be closed when not needed anymore. This will reduce the _Cursor finalized without prior close()_ messages in your log output.

Comment: @EmanuelSeidinger Okay thanks. Finally got rid of that message.

Comment: @pskink What does DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor do?

Comment: @pskink Okay thanks for the suggestion. I dumped the cursor. I will look for some kind of discrepancy now. It's too much text to paste.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an educated guess here. Some of these albums just don't have URIs. It's not a problem with my code. The album art located by other music players was simply pulled from the image files located within the album directories.

**edit**

Nope, this is only a partial answer.